# Stop user from entering trailing zeros c#

Tags: c#

My program allows insert of numbers between 0 - 100.

However, they can only be non duplicates. The problem I have in my program is when the user enters 0, it will enter it into the listbox.

Here is the problem, the user can then enter a trailing zero, such as `00`.This And this will allow the user to enter another `0` into the listbox, which produces a duplicate. How do I prevent user from doing this, so only one zero can be inserted.

```
                            //If pass validation add number to listbox
                            if (int.TryParse(txtInsert.Text, out dnum))
                            {

                                Convert.ToInt32(lstNumberList.Items.Add("\t" + dnum));//Insert number with tab
                                index++;
```

Comment: Where do you check for duplicates?

Comment: Where is your list of values already added?

Comment: ? `if (int.TryParse(txtInsert.Text, out dnum) && !lstNumberList.Items.Contains("\t" + dnum)) Convert.ToInt32(lstNumberList.Items.Add("\t" + dnum))`

Comment: Oh cool thanks it works! :) but anyway to make it produce the error message the value already exists.

Comment: here is a crazy idea - you can use a ComboBox with all available values instead of TextBox, and remove them from the ComboBox when added to the ListBox

Comment: @Slai i can only image something like `for(int i = 0 i < int.MaxValue; i++) comboBox.Items.Add("\t" + i);` which will be invoked on UI thread and even better, in the constructor of the MainWindow

Answer (score 2):

Do not compare `string`s where you are going to have troubles with *leading zeroes*

```
 "1" != "01" != "001" != "0001" != ...
```

but `int`s:

```
  1 == 01 == 001 == 0001 == ...
```

Something like this:

```
// Nothing entered e.g. "  "
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtInsert.Text)) {
  MessageBox.Show("Oops! Please enter a number to add to the list");

  return;    
}

int value;

// Invalid value entered (e.g. "bla-bla-bla")
if (!int.TryParse(txtInsert, out value)) {
  MessageBox.Show("Oops! Invalid number");

  return;
}

// Value is out of [0..100] range
if ((value < 0) || (value > 100)) {
  MessageBox.Show($"Oops! {value} is out of [0..100] range");

  return;
}

// Duplicates
if (lstNumberList.Items.Contains("\t" + value.ToString())) {
  MessageBox.Show($"Oops! {value} is a duplicate number");

  return;
}

...

// All tests are passed, let's add the value
lstNumberList.Items.Add("\t" + value.ToString());
```